# Selenium on Python test result is ran 0 tests in 0.000s

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, automated-tests

I'm doing selenium tests in Python and I have many tests in project. I migrated from linux server to windows test server (browser and tests are running on this server) Everything goes fine, but every new test that is created I can't run and I don't know why. It writes **"Ran 0 test in 0.000s" "OK"** Other test I can run properly.

**Two commands in cmd (first is failing, second is correct):**

```
C:\Python27\python.exe -m unittest discover ../autotesty "test_systemlive_2_4_2_6-7_extensions.py"
C:\Python27\python.exe -m unittest discover ../autotesty "test_systemlive_2_4_2_1_new_rec_unit.py"
```

File **test_systemlive_2_4_2_6-7_extensions.py** - Failed test (this writes to cmd "Ran 0 tests in 0.000s" "OK"):

```
# coding=utf-8

__author__ = 'u-zima00m1'

from lib import selenium_tools as st
import unittest
import time


class Extensions(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        st.set_up(self)

    def test_13_01_extensions(self):
        driver = self.driver
        st.login(self, "bossboss", "Bossboss1")
        st.select_roles(self, "God", "root")
        st.switch_to_page(self, "System")
        st.switch_to_sub_page(self, "CTI")
        st.switch_to_sub_sub_page(self, "CTI Servers")
        st.wait_for_element(self, "//a[@title='New']/img[@src='/experience/img-dist/New.svg']", "XPATH")
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@title='New']/img[@src='/experience/img-dist/New.svg']").click()
        time.sleep(1)

        # Other long code ...

    def tearDown(self):
        st.tear_down(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

File **tests_systemlive_2_4_2_1_new_rec_unit.py** - Correct test (this will run browser and selenium does his job):

```
# coding=utf-8

__author__ = 'u-zima00m1'

from lib import selenium_tools as st
import unittest
import time


class NewRecUnit(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        st.set_up(self)

    def test_10_01_create_RU(self):
        driver = self.driver
        suite = unittest.TestLoader().discover('.', pattern="rex_simulator.py")
        unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=3).run(suite)
        st.login(self, "bossboss", "Bossboss1")
        st.select_roles(self, "God", "root")
        st.switch_to_page(self, "System")
        st.switch_to_sub_page(self, "Recording sources")
        st.switch_to_sub_sub_page(self, "Recording units")
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@title='New']/img[@src='/experience/img-dist/New.svg']").click()
        time.sleep(1)

        # Other long code ...

    def tearDown(self):
        st.tear_down(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

setUp and tearDown in both tests are from the same method - there isn't problem I think. Any solutions?

Comment: Ups... It was because of dash in filename test_systemlive_2_4_2_6-7_extensions.py. Sorry guys, I'm still beginner in Python :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is dash (-) in filename "test_systemlive_2_4_2_6-7_extensions.py"